# Ionic3 / How to let app try to load the image when connection changed from offline to online?

Tags: javascript, html, image, ionic3, offline

I'm asking about something that allows my app to try to load images when connection was slow or offline then it back again.

My current problem that images of my HTML pages doesn't show or load in case the connection whas offline then it become online.

So, is that possible using CSS or JavaScript or typscript or any plugins ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the official [Network Information Plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/index.html) by cordova.

In your online-event listener you could reassign the image src to trigger a new image loading:

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

function onOnline() {
    // Handle the online event
    yourImage.src = 'https://www.....';
}
```

Comment: So, i should give the images names to can use ur code ? Or use hash tag # ?

Comment: You could give them a specific class name. In your code you could fetch all your images for example by `let elements: any[] = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic 3 network plugin

in app main file you can subscribe to network connection and publish an event like this.

```
let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('network connected!');
  this.events.publish('connectionMade', user, Date.now());
});
```

Then on the component where image is to be loaded you can subscribe to this event and load an image again.

```
events.subscribe('connectionMade', (user, time) => {
   // load your image again here

});
```